# zsh: command not found: mysql With MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, mamp

I installed MAMP server on MACOS Catalina to work with PHP but when I try to check MYSQl in terminal it gives me this error:

```
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

I tried to change the path to :

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

but it still gives me error, is there anyway to work around and let me access MySQL through terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MAMP, you should use this bin for calling MySQL

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root
```